# How to fix twint error "CRITICAL:root:twint.get:User:replace() argument 2 must be str, not None"

Tags: python, twitter, python-module

I'm trying to use the twint module to get some information from twitter, in particular the bio. The code example works just fine:

```
import twint

c = twint.Config()
c.Username = "twitter"

twint.run.Lookup(c)
```

yields

```
783214 | Twitter | @Twitter | Private: 0 | Verified: 1 | Bio: What’s happening?! | Location: Everywhere | Url: https://about.twitter.com/ | Joined: 20 Feb 2007 6:35 AM | Tweets: 10816 | Following: 140 | Followers: 56328970 | Likes: 5960 | Media: 1932 | Avatar: https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1111729635610382336/_65QFl7B_400x400.png
```

Thing is, I only need the bio data. According to the site, you can use

```
c.Format = 'bio: {bio}'
```

Unfortunately, this yields

```
CRITICAL:root:twint.get:User:replace() argument 2 must be str, not None
```

I think this may be due to the following code line (from [here](https://github.com/twintproject/twint/blob/master/twint/format.py)):

```
output += output.replace("{bio}", u.bio)
```

Where the u.bio value is assigned [here](https://github.com/twintproject/twint/blob/master/twint/user.py):

```
u.bio = card(ur, "bio")
```

The card function does the following when our type is "bio":

```
if _type == "bio":
    try:
        ret = ur.find("p", "ProfileHeaderCard-bio u-dir").text.replace("\n", " ")
    except:
        ret = None
```

I think the problem may lie in the second part, where a value is assigned to u.bio, either not even being called or returning None for some reason. Unfortunately, I do not know how to fix that or call the function.

I've had a similar problem before with a different function, twint.run.Following(c), but was able to solve it by not setting c.User_full = true

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Shouldn't first Bio be with capital letter? `c.Format = 'Bio: {bio}'`

Comment: You are correct, but that doesn't fix my error. After all, the problematic part is the {bio} being replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format should be of the form

```
c.Format = "{bio}"
```

If you wanted multiple fields

```
c.Format = "{bio} | {name}"
```

I find you get a rate limit of 250 items before a blocker drops down and you need to wait for a few minutes for it to lift.